# Errors in prepared statement - Undefined variable: sql and Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param()

Tags: php, sql

I am getting 2 errors in my code:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: sql
AND
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

My code is:

```
//if there is a plant name
if (isset($_POST['plant_name']) && $_POST['plant_name']) { 
$where .= "AND (common_name) LIKE ? OR (latin_name) LIKE ?";
}
$stmt = $conn2->prepare($sql . $where);
if (isset($_POST['plant_name']) && $_POST['plant_name']) { 
$stmt->bind_param('s', strtolower($_POST['plant_name']));
$stmt->bind_param('s', strtolower($_POST['plant_name'])."%");
}

//execute query
$stmt->execute();

// get the roses and do the query!
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rosename";

//do we have a 'where string' to add to this query
if ($where) {
$query .= $where;
}

$sql = mysql_query($query, $conn2);
```

I am basically trying to get someone to type in a plant in the plant_name field and then see if it is like any values from latin_name and common_name attributes in the DB.

Could somebody please help me out.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT *...`. I presume this should read `$query = "SELECT *...`. Also put a space before the `AND` so that you don't end up with `rosenameAND`

Answer (score 2):

The `$stmt` object is probably set to false, due to the fact the query being prepared was erroneous.

Try this:

```
$stmt = $conn2->prepare($sql . $where);

if (false === $stmt) {
    var_dump($conn2->errorCode();
}
```

You can read up on [error code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) and [prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) via the PHP docs.

ALSO, you need to move the $sql and $where initializations above the $stmt code block. That's why you are getting the undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be preparing a statement using a variable $sql that is undefined, that's what the notice error is saying. In your code we can't see any variables named $sql defined before the prepare statement where you try to use that variable.